# 2048 in Matplotlib

Tags: python, game, matplotlib, 2048

I did an OOP to make 2048 using Matplotlib visualization. The `color` dictionary is for setting different colors to each number in the game.

There are two classes written here: `App2048`, through which we add interactivity and we run the app, and `CellObject`, which is for the cell/square that will have a value/number. objects of `CellObject` can update itself visually, if the value/number changes, through the method `update`. There are `n*n` `CellObject` objects in the game.

The algorithm for the swipe (left/right/up/down) is done through methods in `App2048`. When we swipe left, for example, we want all numbers 'move' to the left, this can be done by changing the values/numbers in the cells. But before changing the values, we must make Python to decide which direction the numbers will move. To do that, we track the movement of the cursor while the mouse button is hold, then if we reach some point P where the vector from the initial point to that last point P has length at least 0.5, then Python will analyze the tendency of the direction of the vector. For example: a vector of (0.1, 1) clearly indicates 'UP' direction because it tends to move north, if the vector is (0.8, -0.1) then it indicates 'RIGHT' direction, etc.

When the condition of swiping (left/right/up/down) is met, then the app object will perform the `go_left`/
`go_right`/`go_up`/`go_down` method, in which the numbers in the cells are updated to show movement. The algorithm: we move the numbers first, without accounting the 'combined two equal numbers'. After moving, then we find adjacent pairs with same numbers and then combined them according to the direction of the swipe, and then moving the numbers again just like we did just before finding adjacent pairs. After swipe, if the values are changed then we will set a new number, 2 or 4, to a randomly picked zero valued cell thorugh `add_new_value` method.

The `solvable` method is to check whether or not we can still make a movement. It checks if we still have zero valued cell, or if there is at least one adjacent pair with same numbers.

The `solved_or_lost` method is quite clear.

---

```
import random
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

color = {0: (0,0,0,0), 2: (0, 0.5, 0, 0.5), 4: (0, 0.5, 0, 1), 8: (0, 1, 0, 0.5), \
         16: (0, 1, 0, 1), 32: (0, 0, 0.5, 0.5), 64: (0, 0, 0.5, 1), 128: (0, 0, 1, 0.5), \
         256: (0, 0, 1, 1), 512: (0.75, 0, 0, 0.5), 1024: (0.75, 0, 0, 1), 2048: (1, 0, 0, 1)}


class App2048:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

        self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots()

        self.axes.axis('scaled')

        self.axes.set_xlim(0, n+1); self.axes.set_ylim(0, n+1)

        self.cells = []
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            row_cells = []
            for j in range(1, n+1):
                cell = CellObject(i, j, 0, \
                                  self.fig, self.axes)
                row_cells.append(cell)
            self.cells.append(row_cells)

        self.cells_2 = []
        for row in self.cells:
            self.cells_2.extend(row)

        c1 = random.sample(self.cells_2, 1)[0]
        c2 = random.sample(self.cells_2, 1)[0]
        while c2 == c1:
            c2 = random.sample(self.cells_2, 1)[0]
            
        c1.value = 2; c1.update()
        c2.value = 2; c2.update()

        self.connect()

        self.press = False
        self.path = []
        self.win = False
        plt.show()

    def on_press(self, event):
        pos = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if None not in pos:
            self.press = True
            self.path.append(pos)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if self.press:
            pos = event.xdata, event.ydata
            if None not in pos:
                self.path.append(pos)
            else:
                self.path.clear()
                self.press = False
                return None

            dx = self.path[-1][0] - self.path[0][0]
            dy = self.path[-1][1] - self.path[0][1]
            vector_length = math.sqrt((dx**2) + (dy**2))

            direction = None
            if vector_length >= 0.5:
                if abs(dx) > abs(dy):
                    if dx > 0:
                        direction = 'right'
                    elif dx < 0:
                        direction = 'left'
                elif abs(dy) > abs(dx):
                    if dy > 0:
                        direction = 'up'
                    elif dy < 0:
                        direction = 'down'
            if direction != None:
                self.press = False
                self.path.clear()

                previous_values = self.values

                if direction == 'up':
                    self.go_up()
                elif direction == 'down':
                    self.go_down()
                elif direction == 'right':
                    self.go_right()
                else:
                    self.go_left()

                if self.changed(previous_values):
                    self.add_new_value()

                self.solved_or_lost()

    def on_release(self, event):
        pos = event.xdata, event.ydata
        self.press = False
        self.path.clear()

    def solvable(self):
        current_values = self.values
        if 0 in current_values:
            return True
        else:
            for i in range(self.n):
                for j in range(self.n):
                    if j+1 <= self.n-1:
                        if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i][j+1].value:
                            return True
                    if 0 <= j-1:
                        if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i][j-1].value:
                            return True

                    if i+1 <= self.n-1:
                        if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i+1][j].value:
                            return True

                    if 0 <= i-1:
                        if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i-1][j].value:
                            return True

    def solved_or_lost(self):
        current_values = self.values
        if (2048 in current_values) and (not self.win):
            self.axes.set_title('WIN', color= 'blue')
            self.fig.canvas.draw()
            self.win = True
            return True
        elif self.solvable():
            return False
        else:
            self.axes.set_title('LOSE', color = 'red')
            self.fig.canvas.draw()
            plt.pause(2)
            plt.close()
            
    @property
    def values(self):
        return [cell.value for cell in self.cells_2] 

    def changed(self, previous_values):
        current_values = self.values
        return current_values != previous_values

    def add_new_value(self):
        new_number = random.sample([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4], 1)[0]
        random_cell = random.sample([cell for cell in self.cells_2 if cell.value==0], \
                                    1)[0]
        random_cell.value = new_number
        random_cell.update(draw=True)
        
    def go_up(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value > 0]
            for i in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for i in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value = positives[i]; self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].update(draw=False)            
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        for j in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[self.n-1-i][j] for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value > 0]
            for i in range(len(positives)-1):
                if self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value == self.cells[self.n-2-i][j].value:
                    self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value = 2*self.cells[self.n-2-i][j].value
                    self.cells[self.n-2-i][j].value = 0
                    self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].update(draw=False); self.cells[self.n-2-i][j].update(draw=False)
            positives = [self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value > 0]
            for i in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for i in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].value = positives[i]; self.cells[self.n-1-i][j].update(draw=False)              
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def go_down(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][j].value for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value > 0]
            for i in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for i in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][j].value = positives[i]; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        for j in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][j] for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value != 0]
            for i in range(len(positives)-1):
                if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i+1][j].value:
                    self.cells[i][j].value = 2*self.cells[i+1][j].value
                    self.cells[i+1][j].value = 0
                    self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False); self.cells[i+1][j].update(draw=False)
            positives = [self.cells[i][j].value for i in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value > 0]
            for i in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for i in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][j].value = positives[i]; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)        
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def go_left(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][j].value for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value > 0]
            for j in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for j in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][j].value = positives[j]; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        for i in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][j] for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value > 0]
            for j in range(len(positives)-1):
                if self.cells[i][j].value == self.cells[i][j+1].value:
                    self.cells[i][j].value = 2*self.cells[i][j+1].value
                    self.cells[i][j+1].value = 0
                    self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False); self.cells[i][j+1].update(draw=False)
            positives = [self.cells[i][j].value for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][j].value > 0]
            for j in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for j in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][j].value = positives[j]; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw() 

    def go_right(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value > 0]
            for j in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for j in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value = positives[j]; self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].update(draw=False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        for i in range(self.n):
            positives = [self.cells[i][self.n-1-j] for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value > 0]
            for j in range(len(positives)-1):
                if self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value == self.cells[i][self.n-2-j].value:
                    self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value = 2*self.cells[i][self.n-2-j].value
                    self.cells[i][self.n-2-j].value = 0
                    self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].update(draw=False); self.cells[i][self.n-2-j].update(draw=False)
            positives = [self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value for j in range(self.n) if self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value > 0]
            for j in range(self.n):
                self.cells[i][j].value = 0; self.cells[i][j].update(draw=False)
            for j in range(len(positives)):
                self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].value = positives[j]; self.cells[i][self.n-1-j].update(draw=False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def connect(self):
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)


class CellObject:

    def __init__(self, row, col, value, fig, axes):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.value = value
        self.fig, self.axes = fig, axes
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        if self.value == 0:
            self.ec = (0,0,0,0.1)
            self.text_color = (0,0,0,0)
        else:
            self.ec = (0,0,0,1)
            self.text_color = (1,1,1,1)

        self.fc = color[self.value]
        
        self.center = [self.col, self.row]

        self.rect = Rectangle([self.col-0.5, self.row-0.5], \
                              width = 1, height = 1, fc = self.fc, ec = self.ec, \
                              linewidth = 2)

        self.text = self.axes.text(self.col, self.row, str(self.value), \
                                   color = self.text_color, \
                                   ha = 'center', va = 'center', \
                                   fontweight = 'bold')

        self.axes.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def update(self, draw = False):
        if self.value == 0:
            self.ec = (0,0,0,0.1)
            self.text_color = (0,0,0,0)
        else:
            self.ec = (0,0,0,1)
            self.text_color = (1,1,1,1)

        self.fc = color[min(self.value, 2048)]
        self.rect.set_fc(self.fc)
        self.rect.set_ec(self.ec)
        self.text.set_color(self.text_color)
        self.text.set_text(str(self.value))

        if draw:
            self.fig.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 8
    app = App2048(n)
```

---

*Tutorial video:*
https://youtu.be/GLTZCLn7WM0